# User Registration form with facebook and normal way

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, wordpress, authentication

I am in a process of making a website which has both php based simple website and along with it has a blog option. I want to make a custom user registration form which I have done in php. But I also want a facebook login button for my form in php.

The other problem I am facing is that when the user enters the blog section he is out of the sign in section.

Can you please tell me a way through which my user remains signed in even when he enters the blog section.

Answer (score 0):

You never mentioned in the question, but since you tagged Wordpress I am assuming the blog is a Wordpress blog. There is a plugin that allows you to sign up with Twitter, Facebook or sign up with Wordpress as a third option. It sounds like something that would work for you.

http://mailchimp.com/social-plugin-for-wordpress/

Comment: thanks the link you gave is very helpful.. and yes you are right I was not able to quote the question properly. But I want to create a login form my self so that i could use this database and connect the wordpress blog with the other site so that the user who signs in with wordpress automatically logs in to the core php site also is this possible.!